# What alternative do I have to a Left Join in this query?

Tags: sql-server, join, reporting-services

I have this query that is used in a SSRS report that someone else created. The left join is the cause of the problem. If I change it to an inner join I get results (not the correct results) in about 15 seconds. With the Left Join I end up canceling the query after 20 minutes.  I added an index to both Budgets.Professionals and Transactions.Professionals with no change in performance. Is there a way to rewrite the query and not use the Left Join?

```
SELECT 
profs.ProfName as orig
,profs.Initials
,DATEPART(year, TransDate) as [Year]
,SUM(CASE WHEN IsFlatFee = 'Y'  OR COALESCE(MT.Admin, 'N') = 'Y' 
    THEN 0.0
    ELSE Units * (aph.assignedpercent/100) * isnull(B.rate, 0.0)
    END) AS ctp
,SUM(CASE WHEN IsFlatFee = 'Y'  OR COALESCE(MT.Admin, 'N') = 'Y' 
    THEN 0
    ELSE Units
    END * (aph.assignedpercent/100)) AS worked_hours
,SUM(Value * (aph.assignedpercent/100)) AS worked_value
, 0 AS billed_hours
,0 AS billed_value
,0 AS billed_netamt
, 0.0 as paid
, 0.0 as wo
FROM Transactions Trans 
INNER JOIN Matters Matts ON Trans.matters  = Matts.matters 
INNER JOIN MatterTypes MT ON Matts.mattertype  = MT.mattertypesdesc
and MT.Admin <> 'Y'
INNER JOIN Components Comps ON Comps.components  = Trans.components 
and Comps.CompType = 'F'
INNER JOIN AssignedProfsHistory APH on APH.Matters = Trans.Matters
and APH.AssignedType = 'Originating'
and Trans.TransDate between APH.EffectiveDate and 
ISNULL(EndDate,'12/31/2099')
INNER JOIN  Professionals profs on profs.Professionals  = APH.Professionals 
    and profs.ProfType = 'Member'
    and profs.IsActive = 'Y'
    and profs.IsBillable = 'Y'
**LEFT join** (SELECT Budgets.Professionals as timekeeper, Budgets.Amount as 
rate, Budgets.PeriodDate
FROM Matters Matts
INNER JOIN Budgets ON Matts.matters  = Budgets.matters 
    and cast(Budgets.PeriodDate as Date) <= '2017-12-31'
    AND MONTH('2017-12-31') = MONTH(Budgets.PeriodDate)
WHERE Matts.MatterID  = '99999-99.003') as B 
    *on B.timekeeper = Trans.Professionals*
    and YEAR(B.PeriodDate) = DATEPART(year, TransDate)
WHERE cast(transdate as DATE) between dateadd(day, 1, DATEADD(year, -3, 
'2017-12-31')) and '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY profs.ProfName, profs.Initials, DATEPART(year, TransDate)
```

Comment: There is little chance that anybody can help with such little information. We would need to see table definitions including indexes along with approximate row counts for all the tables involved here. Additionally an execution plan would help but since you can't get the query to complete that might not be possible.

Comment: There are some visible oddities, like why you are casting as date `cast(Budgets.PeriodDate as Date)`, then doing a date function on the same field without a cast `MONTH(Budgets.PeriodDate)`.  You should always be careful performing functions in where/join because they can nullify the use of any indices.  Otherwise, what Sean said.

Comment: My guess would be that it's not using any indexes on the LEFT JOINed table.  Presumably you have an index on Budgets.PeriodDate but before you try to use the column (and associated index) you are doing a CAST on it.  At that point the optimizer no longer has any idea that the new value is the same as the index because, well, it might not be.  We definitely need to see your table structure, indexes, and the estimated execution plans (since as Sean said you won't have the actuals).

Answer (score 1):

As Sean and Aaron said. There are too many things that are potentially an issue.

You seem (I'm guessing from column names) that you are joining on text columns `mattertypesdesc` for one. In fact most of the work is done against text columns. Even `Matts.MatterID` is textual. This may not be possible in your scenario but it would perform better if the tables had integer primary keys and you join on those.

Anyway, guessing aside.... You might get a quick win if you replace your sub query in the left join with a temp table.

so before you existing query just do ...

```
SELECT Budgets.Professionals as timekeeper, Budgets.Amount as rate, Budgets.PeriodDate
INTO #t
FROM Matters Matts
INNER JOIN Budgets ON Matts.matters  = Budgets.matters 
    and cast(Budgets.PeriodDate as Date) <= '2017-12-31'
    AND MONTH('2017-12-31') = MONTH(Budgets.PeriodDate)
WHERE Matts.MatterID  = '99999-99.003'
```

then in your exisintg query, replace the subquery with

```
SELECT ...
...
...
LEFT JOIN #t as B
    ON B.timekeeper = Trans.Professionals
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with the APPLY operator... remove left join & it's on condition, use  outer apply and include on conditions inside the outer apply script like

```
   AND budgets.timekeeper = trans.professionals 
   AND year(budgets.perioddate) = datepart(year, transdate)
```

Sample

```
OUTER APPLY
       ( 
                  SELECT     budgets.professionals AS timekeeper, 
                             budgets.amount        AS rate, 
                             budgets.perioddate 
                  FROM       matters matts 
                  INNER JOIN budgets 
                  ON         matts.matters = budgets.matters 
                  AND        cast(budgets.perioddate AS date) <= '2017-12-31' 
                  AND        month('2017-12-31') = month(budgets.perioddate) 
                  AND budgets.timekeeper = trans.professionals 
                  AND year(budgets.perioddate) = datepart(year, transdate) 
                  WHERE      matts.matterid = '99999-99.003'

                  ) AS b
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who responded. I took your suggestions and I was able to come up with a solution. The query that I had to kill after running for 2 hrs now finishes in about 14 seconds.

I ended up creating a cte at the beginning of the script.

```
 ;with cte as
 (SELECT Transactions FROM Transactions t
 WHERE cast(t.TransDate as DATE) between dateadd(day, 1, DATEADD(year, -3, 
 @EndDate)) and @EndDate)
```

Then I linked the CTE to Transactions.

```
FROM Transactions Trans
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.Transactions = Trans.Transactions
```

I then was able to remove the 'where' clause that was causing the issue.

```
WHERE cast(transdate as DATE) between dateadd(day, 1, DATEADD(year, -3, 
@EndDate)) and @EndDate
```